# Labels placed incorrectly in pst-jtree

Tags: pstricks, linguistics, pst-tree, pst-jtree

When trying to draw a tree with pst-jtree, the node labels end up all stacked on top of each other. The following code (which requres xelatex) should place the labels at the terminal nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-xkey,pst-jtree}

\begin{document}

\jtree
\! = {}
:{X} 
:{Y} {Z}
.
\endjtree

\end{document}
```

Instead the result is this:

[image]

This happens on several other installations too, after having worked for years. Any idea what the problem is? Here is the log with /listfiles added. It shows the following:

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2020-12-03 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-xetex.def    2020-09-24 L3 backend support: XeTeX
fontspec-xetex.sty    2020/02/21 v2.7i Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
fontspec.cfg
pstricks.sty    2020/06/11 v0.70 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
   xetex.def    2020/08/26 v5.0i Graphics/color driver for xetex
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
pstricks.tex    2020/09/18 v3.01 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
  pst-fp.tex    2020/09/18 v3.01 `PST-fp' (hv)
pstricks-xetex.def
pst-xkey.sty    2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
pst-jtree.sty    2011/01/04 package wrapper for pst-jtree.tex
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
 ***********
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se, and thanks for posting a minimal example document!  This compiles correctly for me, using an up-to-date TeX Live distribution. My guess is that you have an older local copy of something. The log you link to isn't the log for the MWE, though. But the log you show has a very old version of `pst-fp`: 
`pst-fp v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)`; mine shows `2020/09/18 v3.01`. Add `\listfiles` to the top of your MWE and edit your question to show the list.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated with the \listfiles option.

Comment: what version do you get from `xdvipdfmx --version` ? And which latex version do you have?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, `xdvipdfmx --version` gives `Version 20200315`. Latex version is TeX Live 2020.

Comment: what do you get if you compile the example here? https://tug.org/pipermail/dvipdfmx/2020-October/000109.html Is the x in the center or not?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, the x is not in the centre for me.  Downgrading ghostscript to version 9.52 fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tracked this problem down (like Justin) to a difference between ghostscript 9.52 (works correctly) and ghostscript 9.53 (produces the bad output that Justin noticed and I also experienced). I filed a bug report:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=985635

but have heard nothing since filing (March 2021). Does anyone know if versions of ghostscript later than 9.53 behave any better? The current version in Debian is 9.56.

Jim

Comment: Given that the time between the most recent activity here and your information is so long, it might get more notice if you ask a new question and point to this one as your reason for doing so,